# I upgraded to Windows 10 and want to remove Lenovo Fingerprint Manager, but uninstall fails with 'unsupported operating system.' How can I remove?

Tags: windows-10, uninstall, windows-authentication

My Lenovo W540 was originally a Win 8.1 machine and came with Lenovo Fingerprint Manager Pro preinstalled. I upgraded to Windows 10. Since Windows 10 (and 8.1, 8.0 and 7) manage fingerprint authentication natively, I want to remove this clutter.

When I attempt to uninstall, the uninstaller warns with:

> Lenovo Fingerprint Manager Pro is not supported on the operating system running. Please refer to the System Requirements section in the Lenovo Finger Print Manager Pro User's Guide.

I should be able to override or force the installer to uninstall. Please explain a method for this.

Comment: I really regret what lenovo decide to drop support for latest windows. They're dropping support one by one for their software, relying builtin windows software. But it's totally different. Previously, I used Lenovo Fingerprint Manager pro to enroll my fingerprint rather than builtin windows. Because LFMP can enroll my fingerprint for BIOS supervisor password also, but builtin windows doesn't.
I'm still looking for the way to enable this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't uninstall it either, but I did go into settings for the app and turn off all the check boxes, then it let Windows control the fingerprint reader from then on, so it's almost as good.

Comment: This might work as well. I chose to reinstall Windows 10 without the Windows 8.1 history behind it. I chose this route after experiencing more unrelated but similar issues.